# MVC Inheritance with Entity Framework: How do I scaffold a derived type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-applications

Somebody please point me in the direction of sample code for *.net* Controllers and Views of derived classes...

(you might imagine that there would be plenty of resources, I'm not finding any... )

In the project I have a class derived from an Abstract class, EF maps a table-per-hierarchy db, and at runtime the DB look as expected with "UserTypeId" descriminator.

I've overcome initial compile and runtime errors ...

I tried scaffolding a controller based on the derived class, but that apparently leaves the controller ActionResult needing a cast like

```
Parent parent = db.AbstractPersons.OfType<Parent>().Single(p => p.AbstractPersonId == id);
```

further there's a runtime error in the Index view, so I updated the view with

```
@model IList<BeyondThemes.BeyondAdmin.Models.CardCore.Parent>
```

then the model doesn't have the properties needed to render correctly.

Seems a huge number of people must have resolved this, but the ContosoU example (and others) all end short of describing how to scaffold Controllers and Views for Models after creating an inheritance heirarchy.

I'm also interested to find out if EF6 treats Interfaces the same way as Abstract classes, and would appreciate to see examples for Table Per Type (and even Table per Concrete Class).

The latest error is 
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. You have 'fixed compile and runtime errors' and there is some other 'runtime error'. Can you be more detailed? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Thanks for coming to answer my question... there's a problem with the view in that the model doesn't have any of it's properties.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that you are passing a `Model` of type `IList<Parent>` but you're treating the model as a single element, not a collection. If you plan on passing multiple items, you need to add a `foreach` statement to loop over the collection. If you want a single item, you need to change your Model definition to take only a single item (and pass that from the Controller to the View).

Comment: I have the foreach loop in a second part of the table on the view ... the problem is with the .DisplayNameFor() ... I'm not getting why it works for IEnumberable(Model) and not IList ?

Comment: The problem is (just) creating the labels for each column of the table and looping through the header will give repeated column headers.

Comment: Ok, figured out that I can either use .first() on the list like model => model.First().FirstName or in the controller return the veiw .asEnumerable() .

Answer (score 0):

The type(Parent) you are passing from your controller doesn't match the model(IList) of the view